# how to add background in Django2.0 using html or css

Tags: html, css, django, static

I want to add an image inside my django homepage, but I always cannot get the correct location of the image file I want(yellow high light)
The picture below are the thing I type so far:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ecyQu.png

also in the same file

```
{% load static %}
        body {
            background-image: url('{% static "/bitcoin.jpg" %}');
        }
```

Do I need static whenever I want to insert image in Django2.0? also,
I see some people open separate static file and some ppl put image inside the templete. I am confused where I should put? How can put the **background image** inside the html??

thank you so your answering!!!!

update ** this is what I have so far
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jh6bb.png)

updat2 ** the only refer to admin file only, 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aHs9b.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can use inline CSS just for that case. You already have a `.wrapper` element, so if you want to put a static served image you'd do something like this:

```
<div class="wrapper" style="background-image: url('{% static 'default_page/bitcoin.jpg' %}');">
   Your content here
</div>
```

If you want to use in your CSS files, just use the absolute path according to your static configuration. If you serve your static files using `/static` (that means, the path `/static/default_page/bitcoin.jpg` is correct and shows you the desired image), you can just put into the CSS something like:

```
body {
  background-image: url('/static/default_page/bitcoin.jpg');
}
```

Hope that works!

**EDIT:**

As Thomas said, you've placed the image in the wrong folder (inside templates instead of on your static files folder). Refer to [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/) to configure your project the right way.

Comment: I still have a problem, the static file only refer to admin file (see my update2 pic). Why it does not refer to the static/img/ I have??

Comment: You have to add the static folder inside the project folder, where your apps (like `default_page`) are and then add to your project settings the `STATICFILES_DIRS`, seen [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/#configuring-static-files). If you follow the tutorial given on the page I just linked, it will work. Hope that helps, if you need more help just post here.

Comment: I know the reason why. I am using the PyCharm and there is a bug that it cannot read my static file. =[      I understand your concept, thank you Vanessa x100!

Answer (score 0):

You've placed your bitcoin.jpg in the same folder as your templates. Django serves all static file, such as pictures, from the static directory. Only templates go in the template directory. Create a directory called static inside your hompage app, create a directory inside that called default_page, and place your background image there. Restart the dev server, and your image should appear.

Comment: it return a x-image in my page :( do u know why does it happen? <img src='{% static "default_page/bitcoin.jpg" %}'/> it the format correct ? I put in static>default_page>bitcoin.jpg

Comment: the error: [13/May/2018 19:28:01] "GET /static/bitcoin.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 1657
Not Found: /bitcoin.jpg

Comment: that does look correct. have you setup your statcfiles directory in your settings?

Comment: I know the reason why. I am using Pycharm to implement Django. Pycharm has a bug it cannot able to read my static file. Anyway, thank you!!